# db_datawriter vs grant delete, update, insert

Tags: sql-server, permissions, role

I have an application set up in which the service account uses a user defined role which has each object in the database defined with specific permissions. It seems that every table in the database is listed here and they all have update, delete, insert, and select - so, essentially, db_datareader (select) and db_datawriter (insert, update, delete). The role also has select on all views, and execute on all procs.

When a user tries to update a document using a word plugin, with only the user role permissions, the update fails. If i grant db_datawriter on top of the user role to the account and the update is then attempted, it succeeds.

Where could the discrepancy be here? Why if both of these options are essentially giving the same permissions can we be getting different outcomes?

Comment: Would be curious to see what that pluging is doing on the database. You could set up a trace / extended even to capture the query and the error that SQL raise. That would probably give you a hint for the reason why it fails.

Comment: Please post the error message and what calls are being made while doing the 'update a document'.

Comment: to be completely fair, db_datawriter applies at the entire database level - if your perms are applied to specific objects there might be something missing?

Comment: @GabSql has a good point. A trigger that updates a log somewhere that is not granted permissions by the explicit list attached to the login, or even if the update itself references a table that is not in the explicit list, would fail, while with the `db_datawriter` permission, it would succeed.  Is there a specific reason for doing this with individual GRANTs instead of group membership?

Comment: Yes you would have hoped the vendor who supplied this would have thought of all of this and given the correct permissions e.g. to triggers accordingly.. problem is this application is just junkware and now I am expected to make it work!

Comment: If you just want to make it work, db_datareader and db_datawriter are very good starting points - unless you want to restrict it to a more granular level for some reason. If you want to check what's missing, then try climbing the perms inheritance ladder, check if you have multiple schemas, etc. To me, it seems like a waste of time, since it's a vendor-provided app that you won't be able to do anything with. Giving builtin roles to a service account should not count as tampering with the app (you'll want to confirm this).

Answer (score 1):

You say "***It seems*** that every table in the database is listed here and they all have update, delete, insert, and select".  If you have not explicitly verified that insert, update, and delete permissions have been provided on every object via this role; these permissions may be missing on some objects.

The role [db_datawriter] *guarantees* that insert, update, and delete permissions are provided on *all* objects within the database.  This also includes any future objects to be created.